# How to customize confirmation window with three buttons and custom labels in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I would like to have a confirmation window with three buttons third button being the cancel button. First and Second button clickAction should perform some actions.

My code snippet for button calling the confirmation window is.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="state == 'DRAFT'" confirmed-click="submit(data.htmlVariable)" ng-confirm-click="Would you like to say hi?">>Submit For Approval</button>
```

directive for confirmation box is

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
function(){
    return {
        priority: 1,
        terminal: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
            var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
            element.bind('click',function (event) {
                if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                    scope.$eval(clickAction)
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

}])

Comment: SO is not a place where you can ask other people to code *for* you. If you've attempted something and run into a problem, explain what you did, what you wanted and what doesn't work as expected, and we could help. For more info - [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you have a look @ [ng-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dialog) It will give you the flexibility you want

```
    var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'popupTmpl.html' });
    };
});
```

on `popupTmpl.html` you can have as many buttons as you want and listen to their click events

Comment: I was trying with confirmation window bcz I don't want to install a new directive. If there is no way to use confirmation window then i think i need to go with ng dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap dialog.
For AngularJS

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

demo -> plnkr.co/edit/7xUnlRO4tgeTEv3510BE

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried with modal but the difficulty is i want to access the modaControllers scope variables back in my mainController.